# returning a file or a file path to the main activity after startActivityForResult

Tags: android

i have just started programming for android and i have a little question

i got a main activity that calls another activity like so:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), FilePicker.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, PICK_FILE);
        }
```

this works fine and opens a new activity which is like a file manager where my user needs to select a file.

my question is this: how do i return the file (a file is another class i have called Option which holds all the file info)
can i return it to the main activity as an object?
or can i just return strings like the path to the file and its name?

this is my setresult code right now:

```
Intent intent = this.getIntent();

    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();
```

where do i add my object so it will return to the main activity?.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code

```
Intent intent = this.getIntent();
intent.putExtra("PATH", pathValue);
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
finish();
```

Comment: Look at onActivityResult and at the methods of the Intent class in the  android documentation :)